# Dynamic ID of elements

Tags: html, selenium, gwt, automation, pycharm

I open object X and Y with same fields, tabs and checkboxes. Why are ID of checkboxes or other elements different? What is gwt-uid(number)? Please check the attachments.

```html
<!-- Checkbox gwt-uid-1337 / client segment / collateral X -->
<span class="v-checkbox v-widget webdp-ui-checkbox v-checkbox-webdp-ui-checkbox" id="synchronizationCollateral">
<input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-1337" tabindex="0"><label for="gwt-uid-1337"></label></span>
<label for="gwt-uid-1337"></label>

<!-- Checkbox gwt-uid-1824 / same client / collateral Y -->
<span class="v-checkbox v-widget webdp-ui-checkbox v-checkbox-webdp-ui-checkbox" id="synchronizationCollateral">
<input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-1824" tabindex="0"><label for="gwt-uid-1824"></label></span>
<label for="gwt-uid-1824"></label>


<!-- Tab ITEM (collateral provider) gwt-uid-2054 / same client / collateral X -->
<td class="v-tabsheet-tabitemcell" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-2054" aria-disabled="false">
<div class="v-tabsheet-tabitem">
<div class="v-caption" id="gwt-uid-2054" style="width: 148px;">
<div class="v-captiontext">Collateral provider</div></div></div></td>

<!-- Tab ITEM (collateral provider) gwt-uid-2281 / same client / collateral Y -->
<td class="v-tabsheet-tabitemcell" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-2281" aria-disabled="false">
<div class="v-tabsheet-tabitem">
<div class="v-caption" id="gwt-uid-2281" style="width: 148px;">
<div class="v-captiontext">Collateral provider</div></div></div></td>
```

Comment: I'm unclear what it is you are asking. We cannot explain the code you have posted, because we don't have enough details. You have the question tagged "selenium" yet I don't see any code related to selenium. Are you running into an error?

Comment: See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I execute automation tests but I can not use same robot because ID are change every time. So robot can't find identificator. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

### GWT

[**GWT**](http://www.gwtproject.org/) stands for *Google Web Toolkit* is a development toolkit to create RICH Internet Applications. Broadly, GWT is a framework to build large scale and high performance web appliation while keeping them as easy-to-maintain.

### Features

Some notable features:

- GWT provides developers option to write client side application in JAVA.
- GWT compiles the code written in JAVA to JavaScript code.
- Application written in GWT is cross-browser compliant. GWT automatically generates javascript code suitable for each browser.

As [GWT](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html) generates javascript code suitable for each browser the elements attributes are **dynamic** in nature. Hence you see the value of the **`id`** attributes are being appended with a random number, e.g.:

- `gwt-uid-1337`
- `gwt-uid-1824`
- `gwt-uid-2054`